# Get an object for defined value from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, key-value

I have this NSDictionary:

[image: My NSDictionary]

I need to find an object in `champions`, that has a defined value for key `name` (in this case the value entered by user is "Nasus") and then retrieve all key/value pairs from `stats`. Can You help me?

Thank You.

Comment: Please look at the official documentation first in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not reading the documentation.

Comment: I rephrased the question, Can You take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the object from the dictionary `theOfficial` for the key `documentation`:

```
NSObject *pleaseRead = [theOfficial objectForKey:documentation];
```

To get all objects from the dictionary `aQuickGoogleSearch`:

```
NSArray *orEvenTry = [aQuickGoogleSearch allValues];
```

---

Once you've pulled an object out of a dictionary, you can treat it as a normal object.

```
Foo *myFooVar = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];

Bar *myBarVar = [myFooVar someMethodThatReturnsBar];
```

Comment: I rephrased the question, Can You take a look?

Comment: Can you explain why the code I've posted isn't helping?  Can you post some sample code of what you're actually trying and explain the actual result you're getting (versus what you're expecting to get).

Comment: I already know how to get object for key,`items = [allCourses valueForKeyPath:@"champions.name"];` for instace give me list of champion names. But I need to find a specific champion in dictionary and retrieve `stats` for this champion. I'm sorry, I was asking a wrong question from start.

Comment: Pull the champion out and find the `stats` the same way you'd find them if it wasn't in the dictionary.

Comment: Damn man I'm idiot. I'm sorry and thank You for Your help !!!